# Delphi XE4 Database connection to Firebird

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe4

When using a TIBDatabase to connect to a firebird 1.5 database. When doing it statically from within the XE4 environment it connects fine and can open a table. However if I try and connect dynamically from a running exe, using the same connection params I get a "Username and Password undefined" error. This has surfaced as a new error as previous builds of the same application work fine, but now reverting to the same code causes an error.

Even the most basic of test apps gives the same problem, as soon as it is running as an exe it fails to be able to be connected using the same login and password.

There have been no known changes to the Database engine installation, no OS updates, and environment upgrades.

Comment: What is the connection string (or connection properties), Firebird Classic or SuperServer or Embedded, what is your OS, have you tried with a more recent version of Firebird?

Comment: You need to post a source code example that exhibits this behaviour.